# With the hypothetical expression "à ta place", how do you handle this impossible construction "me me mettre à dos"?

Tags: pronoms

> Si je me trouvais à ta place, **j**’aurais pas envie de **me la** mettre à dos.

There's nothing odd about using this sentence construction, as long as it is some other person than yourself that you say you shouldn't make an enemy of.

On the other hand, when you use the hypothetical expression "à ta place", it is quite possible that you end up saying something like the following  as a threatening remark:

> Si je me trouvais à ta place, **j**’aurais pas envie de **me me** mettre à dos.
>
> {with the meaning of}: Tu n'as pas intérêt à te me mettre à dos.

With the hypothetical expression "à ta place", "je" is the subject by default, so *the 1st* "me" is required as the reflexive pronoun. And then, it is also *the 2nd* "me" that I wouldn't want to get on the wrong side of. So you're stuck with two mutually exclusive "me"s conflicting with each other.

How do you work round this awkward phrasing?

Answer (score 2):

I see what you mean with that however, I doubt that... if I were you... I still exist as capable to be myself... Prior to what you call awkward phrasing, there seems to be awkward logic.

Anyway... Talking genenerally, to solve this logical problem of identical pronouns, you just... change the second pronoun for what it represents ("un type / une personne / un homme / une femme + comme moi", "MyName" or whatever of the kind) and postposition it :

" Si j'étais toi, je **ne** me mettrais pas à dos un type comme moi. "

" Si j'étais toi, je **ne** me mettrais pas aCOSwt à dos. "

Apart from this, please note that "*Si j'étais toi*" fits better here than "*Si je me trouvais à ta place*" and please do not forget the negation.

Comment: A common way to solve the "*me me* + verb" issue is to use "*me* + verb + *moi-même*" so that would be the tricky *me mettre moi-même à dos*.

Comment: Oui @jlliagre c'est un bon tuyau en général mais ici, c'est à dire si j'étais toi... qui est ce moi-même ? En toute logique c'est : toi. Donc... ici... je pense que cela ne fonctionne pas.

Comment: Oui, et c'est pour ça que j'ai mis *tricky*. Je pense quand même que ta réponse pourrait évoquer *moi-même* dans la liste des solutions usuelles, même si elle est inadaptée dans ce cas précis.